# Usb not shown for installation

Tags: uefi, usb-installation

I bought a new laptop and I want to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 unfortunately my installation usb drive not shown when i press f12.
I disabled secure boot and also enabled usb boot legacy support.I tried both gpt and mbr schemes versions with Rufus.But no luck.
I was able to install kali 2020.But I don’t know what is preventing to install Ubuntu.Any advice and experiences are appreciated.Thank you.

My laptop is Casper Excalibur G770 and its uefi  is insydeh20 Rev 5.0

Comment: Did you verify your ISO as being valid?  If a box doesn't boot an thumb-drive I've installed a ISO to, I usually try another box (not for install, just to 'try ubuntu' & verify media is good; using the media-validation routines to verify media). If it fails to boot on the second box I usually conclude the write to media failed & re-write (*I may try a third box on occasion, 2xuEFI & 1xBIOS for example, or 1xsecure-EFI, 1xuEFI, 1xBIOS*)  There are multiple types of ISO, and not all writing software handles all types.

Comment: Adding your laptop make and model to question might allow someone to give better advice.  Sometimes one OS might just be missing something needed to boot/install.

Comment: @crip659 the laptop model is not global.It is sold only in Turkey but I have added to the first post.@guiverc I can only try Ubuntu on another laptop because usb can not being reached for booting.But the second laptop is not supporting uefi.it is an old one.

Comment: Could be a bios setting, maybe reset to defaults and try again.  It could also be Ubuntu itself, could try with Lubuntu or Linux Mint and see if they install/work.  Is/was Windows on this machine before?

Comment: It is new and it had no os before.Now I have kali 2020.3 instead of ubuntu (But i prefer ubuntu to it)and  I have also loaded the defaults but no luck. I will try with Lubuntu and Linux Mint.

Comment: I also tried lubuntu/elementary os and mint.Unfortunately Problem continues.

Comment: You know if bios 'sata' is set achi mode.  Some bios have drives set as raid or RST.  Do not change yet since it will most likely mess up kali booting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i installed Ubuntu.I succeed by booting directly with the iso file with the help of easy2boot.Thanks everyone who responded and e2b devolopers.